# Difference between the two methods of reference variables

Tags: java, reference

```
public class Player {
}

public class main {
    public static void main(String []args) {
      Player p1 ;
      Player p2 = new Player();
    }
}
```

In the following program, what is the difference between creating variable using `Player p1` and `Player p2 = new Player();` ???

I am confused at that part.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Java? Could you lease read [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three parts in creating an object in a class.

**Player p2**=new Player();

    `1.Declaration: The code set in bold are all variable declarations that associate a variable name with an object type.
    2. Instantiation: The new keyword is a Java operator that creates the object.
    3. Initialization: The new operator is followed by a call to a constructor, which initializes the new object.`

when you  say Player p1 ; just like in any other language, you just create a reference variable of type Player.

`Player p2=new Player();`

here p2 is been declared, instantiated and initialized.

Note: the object for p2 is created when a new keyword is used and are always created in heap memory. Thus you can operate on its members through the .(Dot) operators.

Answer (score 1):

P1 is just a reference, no object assigned (you can use it later stage).

P2 is a reference with object assigned through "new player()".

Answer (score 1):

Player p2 = new Player();
this uses the constructor in the class "Player" to initialize the p2.

Player p1;
This doesn't make new Player object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx
read the Creating Objects session for more information